# Backup folder on Box.net - similar to Dropbox

Tags: backup, dropbox

Is there a way you can have a folder on your computer which would backup automatically on Box.net like you do with Dropbox?

The reason I am not using Dropbox is for the capacity; Box.net offers 500GB for $15 a month.

If not, are there any other online backup solutions which offer a large capacity and an automatic folder backup?

Answer (score 0):

It's not as cheap as Box.net, but [**SugarSync**](https://www.sugarsync.com/) offers 500GB of storage space for $39.99, and has all the features of Dropbox, but it can sync any folder, so you do not have to keep everything together.

Comment: Check out my profile for a referral link.